# How to set a background image in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I have a reactjs/webpack app and trying to set a background image for the `body` tag:

```
body{
    background: url("../images/some-background.jpg");
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:top;
    background: cover;
}
```

However after loading the components the `body` style is not present in the page. It shows up in the console though. Is there a way to display a background image in the main page whilst having the CSS rule in the CSS file that is loaded by webpack? Is this because Reactjs does something I am not aware of?

Answer (score 30):

You need to store your images in the `public` folder of your project. You can refer to the `public` folder using a forward slash `/` and access your images from there.

For example:

```
<img src="/background.jpg" />
```

You can do the same in a CSS File:

```
.background {
   background-image: url("/background.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Background should be already a String:

`backgroundImage: "url(" + Background + ")"`

You can also use ES6 string templates:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`
```

*you should read this it might help -*

https://www.davidmeents.com/blog/how-to-set-up-webpack-image-loader/

Comment: Looking at his css, I suppose he is not using style in React Component but loading it from a css file

Comment: Im using react-create-app not webpack... how can i fix this

Comment: Link is broken :(

Answer (score 6):

You need to store your images in the src folder of your project. You can refer to the image inside your css file which should be also in the src folder using  "./"

For example:
your image in this directory "src/images/background.jpg"

then you can refere to it inside your css file (which is located in "src" folder) in the following way:

```
.background {
   background-image: url("./images/background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: This helped me/encouraged me to write image in CSS

Answer (score 5):

**Pure ReactJS and Inline CSS**

If you are looking for a direct approach and using a `local` File in that case.
Try

```
import Image from "../../assets/image.png"

<div
style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + Image + ')', backgroundSize: 'auto' }}
>Background Image
</div>
```

This is the case of `ReactJS` with inline styling where `Image` is a local file that you must have imported with a path.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/upasanaa/react-set-background-image) is a simple github repository, I have created for putting background image to body tag. This example does not have any changes/plugins added in webpack config specifically for css.

In your code, if you have similar repository structure as mine then it could be a path issue. 
Hope this solves your query.

Answer (score 2):

I've consistently had problems getting webpack to properly load background images. 
 Maybe it's fixed in webpack 2, but I'm not using it yet.  I have fallen back to  using the `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy images to a directory, and then referencing that location in CSS.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: './src/images', to: 'images' }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

**CSS:**

```
.Logo {   background-image: url(./logo.png); }
```

**React:**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png';  // Tell Webpack this JS file uses this image
console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {   // Import result is the URL of your image  
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to put the image file in the public folder, then try

```
background: url(./logo.jpg) no-repeat;
```

folder structure be like

public
-- logo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using webpack, you may write your stylesheet in a `css or scss files`. it means that you will import it in your app.js. so webpack will use `sass-loader or css-loader` to bundle your css files when you are in develop environment.

So it will not work immediately, the browser will load your bundle.js first,  exec js file, generate stylesheet and insert them into header.

If you want to work immediately, you should write your stylesheet in your html file.

And remember it also take some time to load your background image.

Answer (score -2):

Discovered this by trial-and-error. The key is to refer to the height and width property tag of an  tag which automatically resizes the dimensions.

React

```
import React from "react";
import backgroundFinalStyle from "../../style/styled-css/background-style";
import i from "../../assets/media/calendar.jpg";

const StillBackground = (props) => {
  const FullscreenVideoWrap = backgroundFinalStyle.fullscreenVideoWrap;
  const ImgFull = backgroundFinalStyle.imageFull;

  return (
    <FullscreenVideoWrap>
      <ImgFull>
        <img height="100%" width="100%" src={i}></img>
      </ImgFull>
    </FullscreenVideoWrap>
  );
};

export default StillBackground;
```

background-styles.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const FullscreenVideoWrap = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
`;


const ImgFull = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -100;
`;

const backgroundFinalStyle = {
  fullscreenVideoWrap: { ...FullscreenVideoWrap },
  imageFull: { ...ImgFull },
};

export default backgroundFinalStyle;
```

Comment: He asks for an integration of his image in the css.